# Django Validar Formularios

Tags: python, django, formularios

estoy intentado hacer un formulario para guardar información de empresas, hasta ahora funciona perfctamente cuando guarda a base de datos etc.

Estoy utilizando forms.Form el detalle es que en una plantilla no estoy utilizando {% forms.as_p %} si no cada uno por separado con el objetivo de hacerlo mas claro y en un orden, haciendolo por ejemplo {{form.nombre}} el detalle es que no tengo idea de como validar que los campos estén llenos, en teoría esto tiene un if for is valid pero no logro hacer que funcione.

```
def nuevo_ingreso(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Base_de_datos(request.POST)

        nombre = request.POST['nombre_persona'] 
        telefono = request.POST['telefono_persona']  


        if form.is_valid():
         Guarda!
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no funciona? ¿Ves algún error? ¿Lo haz comprobado en tu base de datos? ¿La definición de tu modelo permite campos vacíos? Por favor, edita tu pregunta con la información faltante siguiendo esta guía: [http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 7):

Existen varias formas de validar los campos de un formulario con [django](/questions/tagged/django), de acuerdo a qué estés necesitando en el momento... quizás lo mas fácil sea con ayuda de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event) { // o el id de tu formulario
        if($('#{{form.nombre.id_for_label}}').val() == '') {
            // aqui puedes hacer lo que quieras, como poner clases de error en tus inputs para especificar el error, lanzar un alert, como sea
            return false;
        }
    })

})
</script>
```

Otra forma es la validación por servidor, seria cuando defines el formulario, te pondré un ejemplo:

**forms.py**

```
class Formulario(forms.Form):
    """
    Formulario de ejemplo
    """
    nombre = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label='nombre')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Formulario, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # desde aquí, puedes definir luego de iniciar el formulario, si los campos son obligatorios
        self.fields['nombre'].required = True, # así no entrara al save(), si el campo no está lleno

    # usar el método clean() para otro tipo de validaciones
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super(Formulario, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
        nombre = cleaned_data.get('nombre', None)
        if nombre is not None:
            if nombre == 'Maria':
                self.add_error('nombre', '"Maria" No es un nombre permitido')
```

Otra recomendación, es que si usas un formulario de `Django`, no saques las variables por medio de la petición, es decir, una forma correcta de hacer la validación del formulario en tus *views.py* seria así:

**views.py**

```
def validar_formulario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Formulario(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           nombre = form.cleaned_data('nombre')
```

> **IMPORTANTE:** Si usas un formulario que hereda de la clase `forms.Form` (como lo pusiste en tu ejemplo, y en el que te puse) no puedes usar un `form.save()`, básicamente porque no está asignado a ningún modelo.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos y comenta cualquier inquietud o duda :D

Answer (score 0):

Al comienzo de tu plantilla, colocas:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
```

WIDGET-TWEAKS: Librería para dar formato a las template HTML, y además hacer llamadas a funciones JS y CSS para cada objeto. Se baja desde:
https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/
se instala:  `pip install django-widget-tweaks`

y debe colocarse en:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

La forma de usar en las templates. es por ejemplo:

```
{{ form.rut|attr:'size:10'|attr:'id:rut'|attr:'onblur:return 
validarut()'|attr:'onchange:upperCase()'|attr:'placeholder:9999999- 
9'|attr:'requiered:True'|attr:'tabindex:1'}}
```

Si te fijas, incluso sirve para llamar a una función JS que valida.